# I made a question using a google acc and after it was moved to a different site, I couldn't use the same account

Tags: bug, migration, user-accounts

I used my gmail to create an account for programmers.stackexchange and made a question https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/191893/why-doesnt-the-function-go-through-all-of-its-steps?noredirect=1 that was moved to stackoverflow (Still don't know why or why stackoverflow if for since the stackexchange site lists no description for it). I logged in using the same email and was on another existing account for that site.

I can't quickly edit or reply to the commments of the original post since I'm on a different account. What could be done to resolve this issue?

Comment: I think that SE ought to create an account and then associate the 2 accounts for you when questions are migrated.

Comment: @SamIam - when a user is created we very intentionally don't make that decision for you.  Showing participation in a site should be something *you* chose to do.  Think of it this way: would you want a profile automatically created for you, including your picture, on a dating site?

Comment: @NickCraver I'd feel about the same about that as I would about someone moving one of my posts from somewhere else to that dating site without my permission.

Comment: @NickCraver [Well OP found a workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15621997/828193) so I guess the system is working...

Comment: @SamIam - the content posted here is immediately licensed under creative commons, owned *by the community*.  You, however, are not.

Comment: I agree with @SamIam, If StackExchange should be able to link the accounts (verify that I'm the same person by making me log in with both accounts) so I can have full access to my question.

Comment: Also can someone mark the question as solved?